# Cypress CSS Locator I am trying to locate a colour picker element from a parent class. I can get to the parent but not sure how to get the child

Tags: javascript, css, selenium-webdriver, cypress

I have a UI with a list of elements, 2 columns.  The first columns shows the name of the item e.g.
Manager, Operator and the list will grow
The 2nd column is a colour picker element.  You can choose a colour
I am trying to find the colour picket element for a name e.g. for Operator
I want to iterate over the elements and find the colour picker element for Operator
From the HTML Code snippet below I want to locate the following line

```
<span tabindex="0" class="colour-select" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span>
```

I can get the list of name elements by using the following css

```
li[class='cdk-drag item container-fluid'] span[class='form-control']
```

I don't know how to go further down to get to the colour-select class

```
<span tabindex="0" class="colour-select" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span>
```

I have the following HTML Code Snippet

```html
<li _ngcontent-ppo-c336="" cdkdrag="" class="cdk-drag item container-fluid" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-data="[object Object]" ng-reflect-disabled="false" rowid="370" orderid="0">
   <div _ngcontent-ppo-c336="" class="row">
      <div _ngcontent-ppo-c336="" class="col-sm-1 form-check">..</div>
      <div _ngcontent-ppo-c336="" class="col-sm-5">
         <span _ngcontent-ppo-c336="" class="form-control" title="" data-disabled="false">Operator</span>
         <!--bindings={
            "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
            }--><!--bindings={}--><!--ng-container--><!--bindings={
            "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "Description"
            }--><!--bindings={
            "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "Colour"
            }--><!--bindings={
            "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "Boolean"
            }--><!--ng-container-->
      </div>
      <div _ngcontent-ppo-c336="" class="col-sm-3">
         <!--bindings={
            "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "Description"
            }-->
         <arm-colour-picker _ngcontent-ppo-c336="" name="colourPicker" ng-reflect-input-id="colourPicker_2" ng-reflect-colour-id="-2">
            <div class="arm-colour-picker" title="1">
               <span tabindex="0" class="colour-select" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span>
               <input type="hidden" id="colourPicker_2" ng-reflect-name="colourPicker_2_dropdown" ng-reflect-is-disabled="false" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" value="[object Object]" ng-reflect-model="[object Object]">
               <!--bindings={}-->
            </div>
         </arm-colour-picker>
         <!--ng-container-->
         <!--bindings={
            "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "Colour"
            }-->
         <!--bindings={
            "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "Boolean"
            }-->
         <!--ng-container-->
      </div>
      <!--bindings={
         "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
         }-->
      <div _ngcontent-ppo-c336="" class="col-sm-1 float-right">..</div>
      <div _ngcontent-ppo-c336="" class="col-sm-1 float-right">..</div>
   </div>
   </div>
</li>
<li _ngcontent-ppo-c336="" cdkdrag="" class="cdk-drag item container-fluid" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" ng-reflect-data="[object Object]" ng-reflect-disabled="false" rowid="371" orderid="0">
   <div _ngcontent-ppo-c336="" class="row">
      <div _ngcontent-ppo-c336="" class="col-sm-1 form-check"><input _ngcontent-ppo-c336="" type="checkbox" title="" ng-reflect-name="checked-371" ng-reflect-is-disabled="false" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"></div>
      <div _ngcontent-ppo-c336="" class="col-sm-5">
         <span _ngcontent-ppo-c336="" class="form-control" title="" data-disabled="false">Minor</span><!--bindings={
            "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
            }--><!--bindings={}--><!--ng-container--><!--bindings={
            "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "Description"
            }--><!--bindings={
            "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "Colour"
            }--><!--bindings={
            "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "Boolean"
            }--><!--ng-container-->
      </div>
      <div _ngcontent-ppo-c336="" class="col-sm-3">
         <!--bindings={
            "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "Description"
            }-->
         <arm-colour-picker _ngcontent-ppo-c336="" name="colourPicker" ng-reflect-input-id="colourPicker_3" ng-reflect-colour-id="-2">
            <div class="arm-colour-picker" title="1">
               <span tabindex="0" class="colour-select" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span><input type="hidden" id="colourPicker_3" ng-reflect-name="colourPicker_3_dropdown" ng-reflect-is-disabled="false" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" value="[object Object]" ng-reflect-model="[object Object]"><!--bindings={}-->
            </div>
         </arm-colour-picker>
         <!--ng-container--><!--bindings={
            "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "Colour"
            }--><!--bindings={
            "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "Boolean"
            }--><!--ng-container-->
      </div>
      <!--bindings={
         "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
         }-->
      <div _ngcontent-ppo-c336="" class="col-sm-1 float-right"><span _ngcontent-ppo-c336="" cdkdraghandle="" class="cdk-drag-handle fa fa-bars order-button" style="touch-action: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; user-select: none;"></span></div>
      <!--bindings={
         "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
         }-->
      <div _ngcontent-ppo-c336="" class="col-sm-1 float-right">
         <button _ngcontent-ppo-c336="" type="button" class="delete far fa-times"></button><!--bindings={
            "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
            }--><!--bindings={}-->
      </div>
   </div>
</li>
```

What css locator can i use to get to the colour-select class please.
Thanks for your help

e.g. code snippet this gets me all the elements of the names

```
static get AudienceColour(): Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>> {                
        const AudienceResourceText = [
            "Undefined",
            "Manager",
            "Operator",
            "Minor"
        ];
        return cy.get("li[class='cdk-drag item container-fluid'] span[class='form-control']").each((item, index, list) => {
            cy.wrap(item).should("contain.text", AudienceResourceText[index]);
        });
    }
```

Riaz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `.within()` you need to navigate up with a `parents` command

```js
const AudienceResourceText = ["Undefined", "Manager", "Operator", "Minor"];

cy.get("li[class='cdk-drag item container-fluid'] span[class='form-control']")
.each((item, index, list) => {
  cy.wrap(item)
    .should("contain.text", AudienceResourceText[index])   // subject is span
    .parents('.row')                                       // subject is div.row
    .within(() => {                         
      cy.get('span.colour-select')                         // gets the color-picker
        .should('have.css', 'color', 'rgb(0, 0, 0)')       // check the color
    })
})
```

Comment: This is good for me.  Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `.get()` selector is too specific.

You have this (simplified) html

```html
<li>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col...">
      <span>TEXT-TO-FIND</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col...">
      <arm-colour-picker...
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

If you cut it down to `li[class='cdk-drag item container-fluid'] .row` you get the rows which contain both the text and the color-picker.

`.should("contain.text", ...)` searches all children of the element specified, so it still works as you expect.

```js
cy.get("li[class='cdk-drag item container-fluid'] .row")
  .each((item, index) => {
    cy.wrap(item)
      .should("contain.text", AudienceResourceText[index])
      .find('span.colour-select')
  })
}
```

This answers your question about how to select the color-picker, but there are more problems related to returning it from the method.

Maybe you want to do this:

```js
static get AudienceColour(): Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>> {                

  const colors = []
  return cy.get("li[class='cdk-drag item container-fluid'] .row")
    .each((item, index) => {
      cy.wrap(item)
        .should("contain.text", AudienceResourceText[index])
        .find('span.colour-select')
        .invoke('attr', 'style')     // grab the style attributes
        .then(styles => colors.push(styles)
    })
    .then(() => return colors)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using using the `within()` command

```js
cy.get(
  "li[class='cdk-drag item container-fluid'] span[class='form-control']"
).each((item, index, list) => {
  cy.wrap(item).within(() => {
    expect(item).to.have.text(AudienceResourceText[index])
    cy.get('.colour-select') //gets the color-select class
  })
})
```